# How to create minutes count down using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program which I wrote with html just like a website but runs offline so I want to add 35 minutes countdown after the user have logged in then when the 35 minutes is exusted the user will be logged out

But I can't get the code right because I am new to javascript but I was able to get it to count for 60seconds and after that it will alert the user with "logout" but I want it to log the user out not to alert the user to logout

This is the html code

```
 <div id="counter">1:00</div>
```

And this is the javascript code

```
    function countdown() {
        var seconds = 60;
        function tick() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            seconds--;
            counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
            if( seconds > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {
                alert("Game over");
            }
        }
        tick();
    }
    countdown();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("July 12, 2017 09:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="counter"
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);   // time changes in every 1 second
</script> 
<p2>to go</p2>
```

try this out, change date and time according to your need

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countdown() {
  var timeoutMinutes = 35;
  var startTime = new Date();
  var elapsedSecond = 0;

  function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var currentTime = new Date();
    elapsedSecond = (currentTime - startTime) / 1000;
    counter.innerHTML = formatPlaces("0") + ":" 
      + formatPlaces(elapsedSecond / 60) + ":" 
        + formatPlaces(elapsedSecond % 60);
    if (elapsedSecond <= timeoutMinutes * 60) {
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Game over");
    }
  }
  tick();
}

function formatPlaces(value) {
  var intValue = parseInt(value);
  return intValue.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + intValue.toString() : intValue.toString();
}
countdown();
```

```html
<div id="counter">00:00</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling sessions in the frontend is not the best way to approach this, but since you asked...

Your method seems correct, I mean you just have to change 60 seconds with 2100 (for 35 minutes) seconds. To logout you'd need a function or a page to log them out.
The problem with this method is that if they refresh the page the counter also refreshes, also they can directly change the javascript if they want, rewrite the function and so many other things...

Luckily for you Javascript now supports something called session storage and local storage, so you can store your timer in one of these variables and even if they refresh the page you don't lose their latest value. Session variables last for as long as the browser is open, local variables last until forever, or if until you unset them.

You can set storage values like this:

```
var latestTime = localStorage.getItem('secondsPassed');
localStorage.setItem('secondsPassed', lastTime+1);
```

This will at least get around them refreshing the page and closing-reopening the browser to refresh the timer!

If you want to learn how to handle sessions properly read into PHP since the backend is the best way to handle these kind of things.

Comment: Antoniu Livadariu this is exactly what I have in mind for my project so that every user will be given 35 minutes then after the time is out the user will be logged out and redirected to my home page named index.html and their time will be saved to avoid them refreshing the time please help me

Comment: Ok here is a link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/28wL7qh6/ , hope it works! If you want to redirect change the alert in the if with `window.location.href = 'yoururl.com/index.html';`